# Stool to love - who am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, story, letters

> *Recently, I was walking to Genua, where I stumbled upon Ego.
>
> He told me some Gordas were chasing him.
>
> Now, I usually don't follow Ego's advice, but before I could doubt him I saw Rozel and Fozel coming.
>
> Hakuma, come! One shouted.
>
> Slightly confused I started running, nearly tripping over a Limp on my way out.
>
> Trying to make my exit out of the city, that Freak was blocking my way, telling me we had some unfinished business.
>
> Fortunately, I saw an alley leading to the Police.
>
> There, I could finally relax. Abe and I even shared some laughs looking back at the whole thing!*
>
> ***Who am I..?***

Hint 1 added on 2019/11/04

> The letters tag is important. However, an anagram is not the way to go.

Comment: Letters tag... Hmmm...

Comment: rot 13 (Vf gur gvgyr na nantenz - "Fgbby gb ybir" = "gbby gb fbyir")

Comment: @Karm, no, it was not intended that way

Comment: Could we get a hint?

Comment: Late response, but hint added. A small one (I think) to start with. If needed, I can add more later.

Comment: Any way to give a hint without giving too much away?

Answer (score 2):

Letters but not anagrams ... Hmm ...

*Recently, I was walking to Genua, where I stumbled upon Ego.*

> Genua isn't a real place, but [Genoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genoa) is.

*He told me some Gordas were chasing him.*

> Gorda isn't a word, but [Garda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garda_S%C3%ADoch%C3%A1na) is, and they might be found chasing someone.

*Now, I usually don't follow Ego's advice, but before I could doubt him I saw Rozel and Fozel coming.*

> Perhaps we can similarly change single letters in the words Rozel and Fozel to make something more sensical.

*Hakuma, come! One shouted.*

> If they're addressing the narrator, then the answer to "Who am I?" should be a single-letter variation of Hakuma.

*Slightly confused I started running, nearly tripping over a Limp on my way out.*

> You can't trip over a limp, but you can trip over a lamp.

*Trying to make my exit out of the city, that Freak was blocking my way, telling me we had some unfinished business.*

> This makes sense even without changing anything, but maybe the capitalised Freak indicates that we should change a letter in that word too.

*Fortunately, I saw an alley leading to the Police.*

> Again, this makes sense without changing anything, and could be a confirming connection back to the Garda from earlier.

*There, I could finally relax. Abe and I even shared some laughs looking back at the whole thing!*

> Who is Abe? The same as Ego? [Abe Ego](https://abeego.com/)?

*Who am I..?*

> A name that's one letter different from Hakuma?

Comment: I think it's possible that: gur anzr unf n ahzore bs ercynprzragf onfrq ba jung bgure yrggref ner ercynprq guebhtubhg gur evqqyr. Sbe rknzcyr, Trahn -> Trabn pbhyq vaqvpngr gung gur "h" va Unxhzn vf fhccbfrq gb or na "b". Jr pbhyq rira unir rknzcyrf bs fvatyr yrggref orvat fhofgvghgrq va sbe zhygvcyr yrggref... lbh pna gevc bire n ynzc, znlor lbh pna nyfb gevc bire n yhzc? be n fghzc?

Comment: Maybe you don’t change the letters, you change the sounds…?

Comment: @swashbuckler I was thinking that the replacement might be sequential: **o** to **u** in Gen[ ]a, then **a** to **o** in G[ ]rdas, then (?) to **a** in the next word maybe?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I thought about that as well - I think that "Ego" might not be a real name, and I think that "Rozel" and "Fozel" might want to be changed in the same way. Romeo and ...Fomeo. I don't know.

Comment: @swashbuckler Rot13'ing some letters would give Romey and Fomey?